# Displaying the contents of a Map over iterator

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

I am trying to display the `map` i have created using the Iterator.
The code I am using is:

```
private void displayMap(Map<String, MyGroup> dg) {
Iterator it = dg.entrySet().iterator();   //line 1
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove();
   }
}
```

Class MyGroup and it has two fields in it, named `id` and `name`.
I want to display these two values against the `pair.getValue()`.
The problem here is Line 1 never gets executed nor it throws any exception.

Please Help.

PS:  I have tried every method on [this link](http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2006/06/4-ways-to-traverse-map.html).

Comment: how do you know its not executed?

Comment: i had inserted a sysout after line one. It did not print.

Comment: You sure that you're dg object is not null or not empty?  Also, is it "MyGroup"?  You have your class in lowercase, which isn't really a good idea.

Comment: @jmort253: nice to bring it up. That was a typo i made when writing the code here.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see whether line1 gets executed. If you do not want to use a debugger, have you tried putting a System.out as the first line in your method ? There is no reason why your //line 1 would not be executed if the displayMap method is actually called

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Map<String, MyGroup> map = new HashMap<String, MyGroup>();  
for (Map.Entry<String, MyGroup> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

using iterator

```
Map<String, MyGroup> map = new HashMap<String, MyGroup>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, MyGroup>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, MyGroup> entry = entries.next();
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

For more iteration information see [this link](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java/)

Comment: Helpful link. But it didnt help in this case. Same again, no result.

Comment: @SunmitGirme of course not I have checked it in my computer, and it gives perfect result. Please check properly.

Comment: @chandraShekhar: yeah i believe the code to display the map contents is correct in any case. There must be a problem with the mapping in the MyGroup class.

Comment: @SunmitGirme yes good guess, problem must be in MyGroup class.